# Remove class "screen-reader-text" in wordpress genesis

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I want to delete this snippet of code from the DOM of my site `<span class = "screen-reader-text"> Submenu </ span>` the site is with wordpress and genesis framework, I already tried with display: none! Important ; with visibility: hidden; but nothing works, is there any function that can remove it from the functions.php?

Below is an image of how it looks in the DOM of the site

[image]

Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, searched the site and found the error in a file of js, I just removed the text and it worked.

[image: remove text]